# Svg background width problem with background-size

Tags: html, css, svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrkCn.png)

[image]

Hello i have a header in the design with the width of 160px and width 100% and i set it up on a div i put height 160px and when i want to but background-size: cover; to also will the width also the height will be increset and will look like this => the background is croped at the bottom here is the code

```
  color: red;
  background-image: url(/photo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 160px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i am not allowed to post picture but maybe is clear what problem i have

Comment: I can help you post the picture in question. Need help?

Comment: yeah i need how you can do that?

Comment: Add a picture by editing your question

Comment: i cant bro lol.

Comment: oh done so you know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to add your specific HTML to the question to get a specific answer

Comment: i got only a div with that class of header

Answer (score 0):

Try to use vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height) to control the dimensions of an element.

So something like:

```
.element {
    height: 20vh; // This is 20% of the viewport height.
    width: 100vh; // This is 100% of the viewport width.
}
```

More info on CSS Units here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp